# How to split String based on specific character without using strok

Tags: c, string, buffer, token

I was able to split the string buffer based on space without using strok function.

How can I also spilt the sring again based on = sign since i am concern about the values after the = sign .

So the logic is :
split string into token based on space -->done
then split each token based on = and avoid using strok--> issue here 
finally store only numric after sign into new buffer

```
int TokenizeString(char * s_String, char s_Token[][25], char c_Delimiter);

int main(void) {
    char buf[] = "abc=3000    Xyz=27.3   rb2act=11.82 ";

    //1.tokenizes each string without using strok
    char s_Token[15][25];
    memset(s_Token, 0, 200);

    int count = TokenizeString(buf, s_Token, ' ');
    int i;
    printf("Step 1 : Split the string  \n");

    for (i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
        printf("%s \n", s_Token[i]);
        // here is the issue , i need to store the result and spilt it again based on the = sign , i am concern about value after = sign
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

// Function to tokize the string without using strtok
int TokenizeString(char * s_String, char s_Token[][25], char c_Delimiter) {
    int j = 0;
    unsigned int i_Offset = 0;
    char b_Flag = 0;
    int count = 0;

    for (i_Offset = 0; i_Offset <= strlen(s_String); i_Offset++) {
        if (s_String[i_Offset] != c_Delimiter && s_String[i_Offset] != '\t' && s_String[i_Offset] != '\n' && s_String[i_Offset] != '\0') {
            s_Token[count][j] = s_String[i_Offset];
            j++;
            b_Flag = 1;
            continue;
        }

        if (b_Flag) {
            s_Token[count][j] = '\0';
            count++;
            j = 0;
            b_Flag = 0;
        }
    }
    return (count - 1);
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly, my parser fails scanning this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string can be split on spaces using `strspn` and `strcspn` and the tokens stored into dynamically allocated pointers.
Not sure what was to be done with the two parts of each token, so this shows the token, the part that preceds the equal and a double that follows the equal. `strcspn` is used to find the equal in the token and `strtod` is used to parse the double. If the two parts need to be stored in memory, an array of structures might be worth looking into instead of pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **tokenize ( char *string, char delimiter);
char **freetokens ( char **tokens);

int main ( void) {
    char buf[] = "   abc=3000    Xyz=27.3   rb2act=11.82   ";
    char **tokens = NULL;
    char *last = NULL;
    size_t each = 0;
    size_t equal = 0;
    double value = 0.0;

    tokens = tokenize ( buf, ' ');
    if ( tokens) {
        each = 0;
        while ( tokens[each]) {
            if ( ( equal = strcspn ( tokens[each], "="))) {//look for the = ( except for = in index [0])
                if ( equal < strlen ( tokens[each])) {//found an =
                    value = strtod ( tokens[each] + equal + 1, &last);//parse for a double
                    if ( last != tokens[each] + equal + 1 && *last == '\0') {//able to parse a double
                        printf ( "token\t %s\n", tokens[each]);//show the string
                        printf ( "up to =\t %.*s\n", equal, tokens[each]);//show the token up to the =
                        printf ( "double\t %f\n\n", value);//show the double
                    }
                    else {
                        printf ( "%s bad token\n\n", tokens[each]);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    printf ( "%s bad token\n\n", tokens[each]);
                }
            }
            else {
                printf ( "%s bad token\n\n", tokens[each]);
            }
            each++;
        }

        tokens = freetokens ( tokens);
    }

    return 0;
}

char **freetokens ( char **tokens) {
    size_t each = 0;

    if ( tokens) {
        while ( tokens[each]) {
            free ( tokens[each]);
            each++;
        }
        free ( tokens);
    }

    return NULL;
}

char **tokenize ( char *string, char delimiter) {
    char **lines = NULL;
    char **temp = NULL;
    char limit[2] = "";
    size_t skip = 0;
    size_t span = 0;
    size_t extent = 0;
    size_t line = 0;
    size_t len = strlen ( string);

    limit[0] = delimiter;

    if ( NULL == ( lines = malloc ( sizeof ( *lines) * 2))) {//allocate two pointers
        fprintf ( stderr, "malloc problem\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    lines[line + 1] = NULL;//sentinel

    while ( extent < len) {
        skip = strspn ( string + extent, limit);//get number of delimiters
        extent += skip;//advance past spaces
        if ( ( span = strcspn ( string + extent, limit))) {//find next delimiter or '\0'
            if ( NULL == ( lines[line] = malloc ( span + 1))) {
                fprintf ( stderr, "malloc problem\n");
                return lines;
            }
            strncpy ( lines[line], string + extent, span);
            lines[line][span] = '\0';

            if ( NULL == ( temp = realloc ( lines, sizeof ( *lines) * ( line + 3)))) {
                fprintf ( stderr, "realloc problem\n");
                return lines;
            }
            lines = temp;
            line++;
            lines[line] = NULL;
            lines[line + 1] = NULL;//sentinel
            extent += span;//advance past the token
        }
    }//loop to end of string

    return lines;
}
```

Comment: Actually I tried to test if value after sign is numeric values suppose  that I have the following string  "   abc=3@400    Xyz=27.3   rb2act=11.82   "; if I have some symbols or letter , the output wil be 3 which is wrong and i need to raise an error ,any suggestion?  user3121023 51

Comment: I need to raise an error so it will not went through strtod function since I have wrong input , i tried to use sscanf but still having an issues @ user3121023

Comment: @ user3121023                                                                                      
 By using the following  if(sscanf(string, "%*[^-+.0123456789]%f", &val)==1) printf("%f\n", val);
    else
printf("not found\n");

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you need is to get those numbers after each `=` as strings and store them in `s_Tokens`.

If so, you could do

```
char buf[]="abc=3000    Xyz=27.3   rb2act=11.82 ";
char *ptr=buf;
char s_Token[15][25];
int i;
for(i=0; (ptr=strchr(ptr, '='))!=NULL; )
{
        sscanf(++ptr, "%24s", s_Token[i++]);
}
```

You should provisions for error checking though.

The output is:

```
3000
27.3
11.82
```

`strchr()` returns a pointer to the first occurrence of a character in a string. If that character wasn't found, it returns `NULL`.